# Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

After installing rvm, updating .gmrc file, updating rubygems and running `gem install rails -v ">=3.1.0rc"`, I now seem to have a complete mess:

```
$ rails -v
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails:18
```

---

```
myhome@myhome-mini:~$ gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/myhome/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/myhome/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/myhome/gems
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gemhome" => "/home/myhome/gems"
     - "gempath" => ["/home/myhome/gems", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, but with the bundler gem.

Comment: Sorry I reinstalled Ubuntu on that machine so I can't comment on any of the solutions suggested..although actually I did try the sudo approach without success so I'll accept the remove ruby suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had to `sudo gem install bundler` to make it work again.

Comment: God, sometimes the Ruby ecosystem just makes me scream and cry.

Comment: What if I already have bundler and it still doesn't work? (that's my case)

Answer (score 85):

I've had a similiar problem. Not sure if that helps you, but you might try to install gems with `rvmsudo gem install [gemname]` instead of just doing `gem install [gemname]` or `sudo gem install [gemname]`.

**I try to explain this a bit because of the upvotes:**
This basically is a path issue. If you set up gems via `gem install`, they mostly likely will be in another directory (e.g. `/usr/local/`) compared to gems set up via bundler (where you can override it with `--path`). Using `sudo` may also set them up into another directory since `sudo` starts a subshell which has a different environment then. This is why you have `rvmsudo`.

If you want to see the differences, compare `$PATH`, `$GEM_HOME`, `$GEM_PATH` and `$BUNDLE_PATH` when echoing directly, with `sudo` and with `rvmsudo`.

Comment: This comment is especially useful for installing gems on travis-ci.org

Comment: i have this issue when creating my own gems and still developing them. In the main app i use path to reference the folder. 

when outside the application directory and I want to do something like rails -v I get this error saying it cannot find a custom gem I am developing. Any recommendations on a potential fix?

Answer (score 6):

I got a problem similar to this, there may be a compatible problem of rvm.
I fixed by updating rvm to latest version:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Then you should reload rvm or just open new terminal window.
Then I reinstalled the bundler 'gem install bundler' and ran 'bundle install' as normal

Comment: If you already have rvm installed and a newer version, this should do the same thing:

`rvm get stable --auto`

Answer (score 5):

```
rvm rubygems current
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

remove ruby first
then

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libreadline5 libreadline5-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

to install all needed lib
then you could install ruby and rails

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm --default use 1.9.3
rvm gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same message when trying to generate a controller after installing IntelliJ IDEA and the associated Plugin for Rail Dev.  From my app directory I just executed bundle install and was then able to generate controllers again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question but I just recently decided to move to RVM on a server I had setup a while ago and was having this same problem where gems were being installed in the wrong place and it was just messing everything up.

After a few hours of crawling through SO, I finally figured out that in my `.gemrc` file in my root folder, I had previously setup the `gemhome: and gempath:` variables and they were messing with the whole system.

After removing these lines, all my gems were working property.

Just thought I would post my answer in case someone was in the same position.