# Heroku GemLoad Error during RailsBridge InstallFest Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running through the RailsBridge InstallFest tutorial.

Currently on [Create a Heroku Account](http://docs.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_heroku_account?back=create_an_ssh_key%23step2), where I am running into a problem on Step 4 > Verify Heroku Version.

When I run `heroku version` in Terminal I receive the following error.

```
/Users/Apple/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-4.0.2, actionpack-4.0.2, activemodel-4.0.2, activerecord-4.0.2, activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3, activesupport-4.0.2, arel-4.0.1, atomic-1.1.14, builder-3.1.4, bundler-1.3.5, bundler-unload-1.0.2, erubis-2.7.0, executable-hooks-1.2.6, gem-wrappers-1.2.1, hike-1.2.3, i18n-0.6.9, mail-2.5.4, mime-types-1.25.1, multi_json-1.8.2, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.5.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-4.0.2, railties-4.0.2, rubygems-bundler-1.4.2, rvm-1.11.3.8, sprockets-2.10.1, sprockets-rails-2.0.1, thor-0.18.1, thread_safe-0.1.3, tilt-1.4.1, treetop-1.4.15, tzinfo-0.3.38] (Gem::LoadError)

from /Users/Apple/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/Apple/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /Users/Apple/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
```

I have attempted to resolve this issue using [Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864791/could-not-find-heroku-0-amongst-gemloaderror?lq=1) & [Toolbelt install: Could not find gem Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574014/toolbelt-install-could-not-find-gem-heroku/13465185#13465185), however it doesn't seem to work.

One thing I notice is that while following the instructions within [Toolbelt install: Could not find gem Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574014/toolbelt-install-could-not-find-gem-heroku/13465185#13465185), when asked to `rm heroku` it says that there is no heroku file or directory.

It appears I should remove the heroku gem and potentially re-install the Heroku Toolbelt. Though, I have done this once to the same result.

EDIT: I have gone head and removed the heroku gem and reinstalled the Heroku Toolbelt, restarting my Terminal after doing so.

Is there any other information I can provide to assist?

Comment: So you used RVM to remove the `heroku` gem, reinstalled the Toolbelt, and restarted Terminal?

Comment: Vidya, yes. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to point out about the comment above, is that you're using rbenv in your path, not RVM. Are you using RVM to remove the Gem, when your path is set with .rbenv?

Check out this stack overflow question: [Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864791/could-not-find-heroku-0-amongst-gemloaderror)

This is the solution one of the people commented with: [Toolbelt install: Could not find gem Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574014/toolbelt-install-could-not-find-gem-heroku/13465185#13465185)

Comment: It looks like I had rbenv and rvm installed through two separate tutorials. I had someone smarter than myself help me figure it out.