# Could not find 'librarian-chef' (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: linux, rubygems, centos, chef-infra

Walking through this [chef-solo tutorial](http://leopard.in.ua/2013/01/04/chef-solo-getting-started-part-1/), I ran into a problem after running `chef solo init .`. Using CentOS 6.5 VM on vagrant, I'm using [chef-11.10.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm](https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-11.10.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm). I installed `knife-solo` via `sudo gem install knife-solo`.

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 chef-solo-example]$ ls
cookbooks  data_bags  environments  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  nodes  roles  
 site-cookbooks

[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 chef-solo-example]$ librarian-chef init create Cheffile
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not 
         find 'librarian-chef' (>= 0) among 30 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in 
               `gem'
        from /usr/bin/librarian-chef:18
```

I saw a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278047/could-not-find-rails-0-amongst-gemloaderror), so I re-ran `sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc`
, but I still ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `librarian-chef`:

```
sudo gem install librarian-chef
```

If you don't have installed `gem` so far, you'll also need to install `rubygems` *before*:

```
sudo yum install rubygems
```