# git post-receive hook not running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, git, bundle

I am having trouble running the post-receive hook as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
cd ~/commodity
git pull origin master
bundle install
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
thin restart
```

I am pushing from local to remote and I am getting this error:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 319 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: From /var/www/html/test
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: Updating a06129c..c3c3da3
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 19: bundle: command not found
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 20: bundle: command not found
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 21: thin: command not found
error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory
```

When I clone my repository on the server and push, the hook runs and everything is great.
Any ideas why the push wont trigger the bundle commands when pushing from my local machine?

Thanks!

Comment: When you clone on the server, are you using a filesystem or SSH path? This is probably something to do with the $PATH your SSH user gets. perhaps try `echo $PATH` in `post-receive` and compare it to `echo $PATH` you see in a shell.

Comment: Hi Ben, I am cloning the filepath, not SSH. I tried cloning using the SSH and now it breaks on the server. Here is my $PATH: /usr/libexec/git-core:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: Are your `bundle` and `thin` binaries in that path? Switch to the user in the SSH path, e.g. for git@hostname:repo.git, do `su git`. Can that user see the `bundle` and `thin` commands? What happens when you try to run them? If necessary, modify `PATH` in the post-receive script so the commands can be found, like `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bundle`

Comment: im using ssh://root@domainname.com/var/www/html/commodity.git. I tried su root and I'm able to run both bundle and thin. I might be running into a different issue as I was able to run the bundle commands a few days ago -- it was only after I installed RVM or a specific gem (sidekiq) that caused the hook to stop working?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this line to your post-receive hook (at least before your first `bundle ...` call):

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

On Unix systems, rvm adds this line automatically to the `~/.bash_profile`. In any none-bash contexts (crontab, git hooks) you have to add it manually.

Comment: remote: hooks/post-receive: 2: [[: not found