# whenever gem not working, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, whenever

I am using Whenever gem to schedule some work on my site.
Currently I am working on development environment.

I have instaled gem as guide suggests.

In **schedule.rb**

```
 every 2.minutes do

  rake "vip_recomend:give"
 end
```

In lib/tasks/**vip_recomend.rake**

```
   namespace :vip_recomend do
      desc "Give vip recomend to ads that are in waiting list"

      task give: :environment do

        girls = Girl.all
           girls.each do |girl|               
               BlacklistMailer.blacklisted(girl).deliver                    
           end  

           user = User.first
            UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver

      end   
    end
```

**Then I tried these comands:**

```
whenever --set environment=development --update-crontab
```

**or**

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

Nothing happens.

Then I check if cron is updated with my stuff with this:

```
crontab -l
```

Output:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/my_host/blogs/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/my_host/blogs && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake vip_recomend:give --silent >> /log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/my_host/blogs/config/schedule.rb
```

When I try to run rake task from console it works.

Any help on this?
Thanks.

**Update 1**

when in schedule.rb I have this

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
```

In cron error logs I get this message.

```
/opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /home/individualki/rubyvenv/ror/2.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I changed Whenever to Rufus-scheduler.

Before that I tried EVERY possible solution to fix my problem.
I think problem was in my Ruby installation on shared hosting, but I didn't have time to examine it.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing your jobs in `schedule.rb` in the following format, with a specified environment:

```
every 2.minutes do
  rake "vip_recomend:give", :environment => 'development'
end
```

Then go to your command prompt, and from within your application directory, try the following:

```
$ whenever --update-crontab
$ whenever
```

You should see that whenever lists your tasks with `ENV=DEVELOPMENT` now.

Comment: I added ':output => 'log/cron.log' and now I get this /bin/bash: bundle: command not found in cron.log

Comment: Can you try running 'bundle update' from your command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

*PATH* problem may be, by putting the following at the top of the schedule.rb, ensure correct bundle path

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
```

Or try to add following if above one not work.

```
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
```

Comment: thanks but still some issues. Also updated my question with some error messages.

Comment: When I want to use rails commands using SSH, then I have to execute this command ' source rubyvenv/ror/2.1/bin/activate'

Comment: Seem bundle gem not found, try with `gem install bundler` and read form [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166081/could-not-find-bundler-error)

Comment: Thanks but I have installed bundler . gem list bundler returns bundler (1.8.2)