# Rails: How to change Bundler default version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.17.2)

How could I change the default to 2.0.1

Comment: When I installed I set gem install --default bundler -v 'X.x.x' but now I have 2 defaults.

Comment: @Lomefin The previous version's gemspec must be removed from the /default directory. Eg `$ mv /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/bundler-1.17.2.gemspec ../` Note that this command moves the spec from /default into /specifications. It is no longer a default.

Comment: I guess you are mistaking what default gems are. They are not indicating default versions. See: https://stdgems.org/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What helped me is to delete the current default manually from the folder
`lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\specifications\default\`
and then install fresh bundler as usually
`gem install bundler`
or as default
`gem install --default bundler`

Answer (score 50):

Following https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html#upgrading-applications-from-bundler-1-to-bundler-2, here's what worked for me:

```
gem install --default bundler
gem update --system
bundle update --bundler
```

Answer (score 23):

I had this same concern when trying to setup Bundler gem 2.2.11 as the default gem on my machine.

**Here's how I achieved it**:

First, I listed and uninstalled all other versions of the Bundler gem because I did not need them:

```
gem list bundler
gem uninstall bundler
```

If you encounter an error like this

```
Gem bundler-2.1.4 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Simply run the command below to get your ruby installation directory:

```
gem environment | grep "INSTALLATION DIRECTORY"
```

This should display an output like this. In my case my ruby version was `2.7.2`:

```
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/mycomputer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
```

Next, navigate to the `specifications/default` directory of the `INSTALLATION PATH`:

```
cd /home/mycomputer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default
```

Remove/delete the `bundler.gemspec` file that you have there. In my case it was `bundler-2.1.4.gemspec`, so I ran the command:

```
rm bundler-2.1.4.gemspec
```

Next, I installed the Bundler gem 2.2.11 and made it the default gem:

```
gem install --default bundler -v 2.2.11
```

Next, I listed my Bundler versions:

```
gem list bundler
```

Finally, I updated my gems to use the newly installed Bundler:

```
gem update --system
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Why couldn't you just `gem install --default bundler -v 2.2.11` earlier to solve the problem of not being able to remove the newer version?

Comment: Doing so you end up with to different versions if the bundler gem, but both being marked as default @iconoclast.

Comment: Doing so results in **two** different versions of the `bundler` gem, both being marked as `default`. (Very sorry... I repeated what was already written because I cannot edit the comment.) Also, you may be able to resolve the issue of two default versions of bundler here: [How can I remove default version of bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59636874/664833)

Comment: I still end up with a different default version when running `bundler -v` after successfully running those instructions.

Answer (score 9):

You need to remove `.spec` file to remove the gem.

Steps:

1. `gem env` – try to search in provided list under **GEM PATHS**, in `specifications/default`
2. remove there `bundler-VERSION.gemspec`
3. install bundler, if you don't have specific: `gem install bundler:VERSION --default`

Answer (score 4):

```
gem install --default bundler:<version>
```

Comment: Already covered in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know where the default specs are, so use `gem environment` to find out.

the steps I used were:

```
gem environment
# note INSTALLATION DIRECTORY
cd <installation_dir>
cd specifications/default
rm bundler-2.1.4.gemspec
gem install --default bundler -v 2.2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the default version of Bundler used in your Rails application, you can specify the version in your Gemfile and then update it. Here's how you can do it:

Specify the Desired Bundler Version:

In your Gemfile, add the version of Bundler you want to use:

gem 'bundler', 'x.x.x'
Replace 'x.x.x' with the specific version of Bundler you want to use.

Update Bundler:

Open your terminal and run the following command:

gem install bundler -v x.x.x
Again, replace 'x.x.x' with the specific version of Bundler you want to set as default.

Update Gems:

After changing the Bundler version, you'll need to update the gems in your application:

bundle update
This will update all the gems in your application according to the version specified in your Gemfile.

Verify Bundler Version:

You can verify the Bundler version in your Rails application using the following command:

bundle -v
This will display the currently active version of Bundler.

Now, Bundler should use the version specified in your Gemfile by default for this Rails application.

Keep in mind that if you're working on multiple Rails projects, each project can have its own version of Bundler specified in its Gemfile. This allows you to use different versions of Bundler for different projects if needed.