# Rails: How can I remove default version of bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I tried to change default bundle version but it getting updated with 2 default version. How can I modify to single default?

```
$ gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.16.6, default: 1.16.2)
```

If I do gem uninstall not removing defaults,

```
$ gem uninstall bundler
Successfully uninstalled bundler-2.0.1


$ gem list bundle

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 1.16.6, default: 1.16.2)
```

How can I set (like the below) default as single version?

```
bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.16.6)
```

Comment: Try with `gem uninstall bundler --version 1.16.6`, and if this works try installing the version you want.

Comment: Tried but getting the Error
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "bundler" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

Comment: which version of ruby do you have?? are you using rvm?

Comment: ruby --version
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: As this is taged with `ruby-on-rails`, try setting the desired version in the Gemfile.

Comment: Try this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691098)

Comment: Thanks Lyzard! This is made that version(1.16.2) as global. We can't uninstall 1.16.2

Answer (score 56):

For those who use rbenv, let say by accidentally you have two default versions

```sh
$ gem list | grep bundler
bundler (default: 2.1.4, default: 1.17.2)
```

Check your gem installation path

```sh
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
.
.
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
.
```

Go to the `specifications/default` directory and look for bundlers gemspec

```sh
$ cd /home/yohanes/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/specifications/default
$ ls -lah
total 200K
drwxr-xr-x 2 yohanes yohanes 4,0K Jun  1 10:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 yohanes yohanes  20K Jun  1 10:05 ..
.
.
-rw-r--r-- 1 yohanes yohanes  16K Jun  1 10:05 bundler-1.17.2.gemspec
-rw-r--r-- 1 yohanes yohanes  15K Jun  1 09:31 bundler-2.1.4.gemspec
.
.
```

Remove the version that you need to remove

```sh
$ rm bundler-2.1.4.gemspec
```

Check again

```sh
$ gem list | grep bundler
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
$ gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 1.17.2)
```

but, if you check bundle version, you still get the deleted version as default

```sh
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 2.1.4
```

So we have to overrides it by reinstalling the required bundler version again

```sh
$ gem install bundler --version '1.17.2'
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Then, if you check again it will show you the desired version

```sh
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.17.2
```

Comment: this is the best answer ever!

Comment: Even after `gem install bundler` again, `bundle -v` still shows the wrong version. Any advice?

Comment: This just helped me

Comment: mine still shows the version that I just removed. Then when i go to my xcode project and run bundle install - it gives me a warning about the lockfile version doesnt match

Comment: (1) If after all the above the old version is still there when you run `bundle -v`, try running `bundler _2.1.2_ install` with the explicit version, it fixed it for me.
(2) This also works with ruby versions through `.asdf`.
(3) I also still have the problem @cspam mentioned with the lockfile warning, not sure what's the "correct" way to resolve it...

Comment: In my case, `gem install bundler --version 'x.x.x'` worked as suggested, but after I still needed to do `gem install bundler:2.3.15` (even though it was already installed). Note that `gem install bundler -v 2.3.15` was not sufficient.

Comment: I had been trying this command `gem install --default bundler:2.2.30`, it installed the gem and set it as default too but it did not change the bundler version returned by `bundler -v`, running `gem install bundler --version '2.2.30'` did work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: no such directory "default", I use rvm

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem but with a newer version

```
$ gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.1.4, default: 2.1.2)
```

But after following indications on this post [Two default versions of rake installed - how to delete one](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2157#issuecomment-361848548) allowed me to deleted one.

---

You have to delete the **.gemspec** file corresponding to the default gem you want to delete.

So first, locate where those files are.

```
# I'm running RVM to manage my Ruby versions

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/

-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff  10731 Dec 26 17:22 bundler-2.1.2.gemspec
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff  15134 Jan  7 17:30 bundler-2.1.4.gemspec
```

Delete the one you don't need.

```
$ rm ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/bundler-2.1.2.gemspec
```

Then install (or reinstall) the gem you want to set as default.

```
$ gem install bundler:2.1.4 --default

Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4 as a default gem
```

Finally you'll have installed only the version you wanted.

```
$ gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.1.4)
```

Comment: Tried all that so many times, and gem list bundler and gem info bundler all say the correct version, but `bundler --version` prints old version, and bundle install still doesn't work. Pulling my hair out!

Comment: @animatedgif please run: bundler install

Comment: @animatedgif if you have a BUNDLER_VERSION environment variable set, changing/removing that might help make the difference ... I had the same problem.  Check with `env | grep -i bundle`; you can `unset BUNDLER_VERSION` if you need to

Answer (score 5):

`gem update --system`

This command work for me

After run try this `gem list bundler`

Comment: this is updating all of your gems, practically...that can lead to dependencies issues and other conflicts...

Comment: `gem update --system` always fails on macOS Catalina even with `sudo`.

Comment: Updating system for this? ah.. no... this is a local installation, nothing to do with global system update

Answer (score 3):

With some bundler versions: you just get:

```sh
gem list bundler 
# bundler (2.1.4, default: 1.17.3)
```

- you install new version of bundler, set it to default and you get multiple default bundler versions

```sh
gem install --default bundler -v2.3.8
# bundler (default: 2.3.8, 2.1.4, default: 1.17.3)
```

- and than you can reinstall old default version without --default parameter so it would be reinstalled as non-default and than you can uninstall it.

```sh
gem install bundler -v1.17.3
# bundler (default: 2.3.8, 2.1.4, 1.17.3)
```

- and uninstall old default one

```sh
gem uninstall bundler -v1.17.3
# bundler (default: 2.3.8, 2.1.4)
```

Comment: I get invald option --default for older rubygems versions

Comment: than try ```gem update --system``` may be you have not a bug but lower system bundler gem version

Comment: yup, I got an old version because I need an older version so updating is not a solution in my case

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got `Gem bundler-2.1.4 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
Successfully uninstalled bundler-2.1.4` And then it re-appeared as a default gem. Using `rbenv`.

Answer (score 2):

The rbenv path to the offending default .gemspec should be like below.

```
/Users/yourusername/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/bundler-2.1.2.gemspec
```

Answer (score 2):

I observed that sometime default gems are not present in the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` path provided in the output of `gem environment` command.

I observed this problem in `Alpine` OS where `Ruby v2.7.0` is installed.

In such cases you can use `gem list -d <GEM_NAME> -v <VERSION>` command to get the location where default `gem` is installed.

```
/ # gem list -d rexml -v 3.2.3

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rexml (3.2.3)
    Author: Kouhei Sutou
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/rexml
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0

    An XML toolkit for Ruby
```

To remove default version you can use `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0` shown in above output. Delete command will be:

```
rm -rf <INSTALLED_AT_PATH>/specifications/default/<GEM_NAME>-<VERSION>.gemspec
```

For example:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/rexml-3.2.3.gemspec
```

Answer (score 1):

Came late to the party but perhaps my findings may help somebody:

After Ruby 2.6 bundler became a default gem this means that [for each ruby version there's a default bundler](https://stdgems.org/bundler/), and the bundler gem comes with an executable `bundle` command.

You can't remove this gem and the only way to update the default gems is to update the RubyGems system using `gem update --system [<version>]`

I Had a lot of problems removing files in install paths to force the default gem, I wouldn't recommend but YMMV. In order to have a ruby 2.6.x with a 2.x default and working bundler, I had to start from a clean ruby installation and update the Rubygems to the point it had the bundler version that the project required.

Answer (score 1):

As @theist points out, after Ruby 2.6 bundler became a default gem. So depending on your version of Ruby, you will have a different version of bundler included. You can see the list [here](https://stdgems.org/bundler/).

But what has not been explained in the answers so far is that you can control which version of bundler is used by editing your `Gemfile.lock` and specifying the version you want to use on the very last line of the file, where it says:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.33
```

This feels completely backwards since `Gemfile.lock` is supposed to be generated automatically by bundler, but that is the state of things at this point.

So, let's explain it all with an example. Let's say I am using Ruby 3.0.3. This version of Ruby comes with bundler 2.2.32. But my hosting company, Heroku, is using bundler 2.2.33. Since I want my dev environment to use the same bundler version as my production environment, I want to use 2.2.33.

So the first thing to do is `gem install bundler -v "2.2.33"`. Then change the very bottom line of `Gemfile.lock` to say that it was bundled with `2.2.33` like:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.33
```

Now when you run `bundle install` it will use bundler `2.2.33`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default one at `/usr/local/bin/`, so if you delete that one and have ruby installed with homebrew for instance, it will dafault to the one that homebrew has.

After deleting it you should see something like:

[image]

`open . /usr/local/bin/`

`bundler -v`

Bundler version 2.3.25

`which bundler`

/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundler

If and only if you are using ruby with homebrew, make sure you have it exported to your path: `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score -1):

TLDR: uninstall ruby & then reinstall it.

Details:

For others using `rbenv` who have exhausted other ideas, the following worked for me:

- exit your project directory (e.g. `cd /tmp`)
- uninstall ruby (e.g. `rbenv uninstall 2.6.6`)
- reinstall ruby (e.g. `rbenv install 2.6.6`)
- return to your project directory (`cd -`)
- install the RubyGems you desire (e.g. `gem install bundler:2.1.4`)

In your project directory you will see something like this:

```
-bash> gem list | grep bundle
bundler (2.1.4, default: 1.17.2)
```

Outside your project directory (e.g. `cd /tmp`) you will see something like this:

```
-bash> gem list | grep bundle
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
```