# Ruby get how to install specifice bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

im new to ruby
i installed ruby 2.7.2
and i like to install a specific bundler version
when i run :

```
gem cleanup
 gem cleanup bundler
 gem list bundler
 bundle install 2.2.5
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean up complete
bundler (default: 2.1.4)
ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["2.2.5"]
Usage: "bundle install [OPTIONS]"
```

how do i install specifice bundler version?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59636874/5347939) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove default version of bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306611/how-can-i-remove-default-version-of-bundler)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is achieved by the command:

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.5
```

instead of

```
bundle install 2.2.5
```