# Messed up! How to uninstall gem bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I kinda messed up when trying to solve a problem.

I was looking up some solutions to solve this problem

```
 cap staging deploy
rbenv: cap: command not found

The `cap' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  3.0.0
```

One solution I came across has something to do with gem install bundler

To check my gem bundler, I ran `gem list bundler` which listed nothing so I ran `gem install bundler` which installed `bundler (2.2.23)`.

However, when I ran `bundle install`, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/kiki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/kiki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/kiki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

So I wanted to uninstall/undo the steps I took. However, typing in `gem uninstall bundler` and `gem uninstall bundler -v 2.2.23` didn't work! It kept returning `Gem 'bundler' is not installed` and in fresh terminal, when I ran the command again, it returns `Gem bundler-2.2.23 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try to call [rbenv rehash](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash). What return `where bundler` and `rbenv which bundler`? May be try to call `bundler` with full path.

Comment: That's what I get when I typed in `where bundler` : /Users/kiki/.rbenv/shims/bundler
/Users/kiki/.rbenv/shims/bundler
/usr/bin/bundler

Comment: and `rbenv which bundler` returns `/Users/kiki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundler`

Comment: Do I go to the folder and delete this file?

Comment: No, just try to call bundler with full path`/Users/kiki/.rbenv/shims/bundler install`. And you have typo - not `bundle install` but `bundler install`.

Comment: I don't want to use bundler. I wanted to use bundle instead. So I wanted to delete gem bundler and clear the default gem

Comment: What does `bundler install` do? Will it overwrite the gem bundler default version?

Comment: No, it will not overwrite. `bundler install` install gems that are listed in Gemfile. Your error "can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)" is [bundler bug](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html)

Comment: Never mind. I got it working by following the instructions inhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306611/rails-how-can-i-remove-default-version-of-bundler