Rails + Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError + Unable to resolve dependency: user requested bundler
Trying to deploy the code using capistrano and got below error
Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'bundler (= 1.17.2)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
Now by mistake, Two default bundler installed and wishing to remove 1.17.2 but uninstall command is not working.
$ gem list bundler
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (default: 2.2.32, default: 1.17.2)
bundler-audit (0.9.0.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capistrano-bundler (2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)

Ruby 2.6.6 - Rails 5.2.3

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306611/rails-how-can-i-remove-default-version-of-bundler
