# How to remove an old version of bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

The root issue I'm having is this error: `You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.`

I get the error even if I just use the `rails` command with no arguments.

When I run `gem list bundler` I see: `bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.2)`

How can I remove the old version of bundler, or set the new version as the default?

Thanks.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761120/how-to-change-bundler-default-version

Answer (score 1):

did you try?

```
gem uninstall bundler --version 1.17.2
```

or

```
gem install --default -v2.0.2 bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running `gem update --system`

I don't know how that fixed anything or why... because `gem list bundler` still says `bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.3)`